# best way to create a global variable in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, variables

All of my controllers (requestMapping url) start with the same variable.

```
myController/blablabal
```

I am thinking about creating a global variable to replace "myController" so in the future if I change the URL name, I only need to change at one place.
The way I am currently doing this is to create a bean.
My bean config file:

```
<bean id="controllerURL" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg type="String" value="tt"/>
</bean>
```

Then in my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/${controllerURL}/qrcode/blablbal", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

However, it seems that I can not access this variable `controllerURL` correctly. Am I missing anything here? Or do we have a better way to create a global variable in Spring MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a *constant* and use it. The compiler will merge the constant and the remaining url at compile-time.

```java
public class MyConstants {
    public static final String PATH_PREFIX = "/myController/blablabal";
}
```

```java
import MyConstants.PATH_PREFIX;

@Controller
public class MyController {
    @RequestMapping(path = PATH_PREFIX + "/qrcode/blablbal", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    // method here
}
```

Comment: That's why I was thinking about..but I really want to learn how to create a bean as global variable.

Answer (score 2):

I would create a BaseController with the base URL

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;


@RequestMapping("/base")
public class BaseController {
}
```

and implement it

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


@RestController
public class MyController extends BaseController{

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    String hello(){
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create global variable **using bean** as below.

1.In your **bean declaration**,

Use `java.lang.String` **instead** of `String` in constructor type attribute.

```
<bean id="controllerURL" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="tt"/>
</bean>
```

2. In your **Controller**,

   @Autowired 
   String controllerURL;

and

```
@RequestMapping(value = controllerURL +"/qrcode/blablbal", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Comment: When I tried this, it said attribute has to be constant. I believe controllerURL has to be " static final".

Comment: if it has to be "static final", then it probably has to be initialized.